# Autofill datetime in Pandas by previous increment

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

Given previous datetime values in a Pandas DataFrame--either as an index or as values in a column--is there a way to "autofill" remaining time increments based on the previous fixed increments?

For example, given:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]},
                      index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
                               pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
                               pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:10'),
                               np.nan,
                               np.nan])
```

I would like to apply a function to yield:

|  | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2013-01-01 09:00:00 | 0.0 |
| 2013-01-01 09:00:05 | 1.0 |
| 2013-01-01 09:00:10 | 2.0 |
| 2013-01-01 09:00:15 | NaN |
| 2013-01-01 09:00:20 | 4.0 |

Where I have missing timesteps for my last two data points. Here, timesteps are fixed in 5 second increments.

This will be for thousands of rows. While I might reset_index and then create a function to apply to each row, this seems cumbersome. Is there a slick or built-in way to do this that I'm not finding?

Comment: Aren't those 5 second intervals (not minutes)? Also, I'm not clear on the logic you want to use to fill in missing time intervals.  For example, what if the sampling is mixed, e.g. 5 seconds, 15 seconds, 10 seconds, etc.

Comment: @Alexander, Correcting 5 sec to 5 min, though for the sake of demonstration, either would do. Also this is for fixed sampling. I'll add language explicitly stating that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first index value is a valid datetime and all the values are spaced 5s apart, you could do the following:

```
df.index = pd.date_range(df.index[0], periods=len(df), freq='5s')
>>> df
                       B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:05  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:10  2.0
2013-01-01 09:00:15  NaN
2013-01-01 09:00:20  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution might work for you,but also use reset_index() fuction.

```
new_dateindex=pd.Series(pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),periods=1000,freq='5S'),name='Date')
```

#'periods=1000' can change to 'periods=len(df.index)'

```
df.reset_index().join(new_dateindex,how='right')
```